# Query for bbPress replies to current topic?

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, bbpress

I'm using bbPress. I'm in a single page of the custom post type `bbp_topic`. As you can imagine this custom post type stores another custom post type called `bbp_reply`. I'm using the following query to list the most voted replies at the top (like Youtube), helped by the GD start rating plugin:

```
        <?php $custom_posts = new WP_Query(); ?>
        <?php $custom_posts->query('gdsr_sort=thumbs&post_type=bbp_reply&posts_per_page=2'); ?>
        <?php while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="content-block-2">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The problem is that the query is listing all the replies from all the `bbp_topic` custom post type. I need to query something like this: list all the custom post types `bbp_reply` from this single `bbp_topic` custom post type you are viewing right now.

(I know how to get the ID of the current `bbp_topic` custom post type: `$post->ID` but I'm not very sure how to use it).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It appears the topic of a reply is stored in the `_bbp_topic_id` meta field](http://trac.bbpress.org/browser/branches/plugin/bbp-includes/bbp-reply-template.php?rev=2955#L1051). Older versions stored this in the `post_parent` field, but it seems this is deprecated? So you can add `'&meta_key=_bbf_topic_id&meta_value=' . $post-ID` to your query to get only replies to this topic.

Comment: @Jan Fabry Yes, `post_parent=' . $post-ID` did it.